# DCos Kafka Certificate error

Tags: apache-kafka

I am facing CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when I am running the create topic command. I have all the proxies unset. please let me know what am I missing?

```
./dcos kafka topic create topictest
```

return

```
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/w527911/.dcos/subcommands/kafka/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dcos/http.py", line 100, in _request
    raise DCOSException('URL [{0}] is unreachable: {1}'.format(url, e))
dcos.errors.DCOSException: URL [https://bdtedcr2n5.svr.us.jpmchase.net/service/kafka/v1/topics] is unreachable: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:765)
```